Installing Cassandra: RedHat - Only version 4.1~alpha1-1 is available
It looks like some configuration of the rpm repository for Cassandra 41x has changed and means only version 4.1~alpha1-1 is available.
We are deploying a stack which includes Cassandra using Ansible. The Cassandra version 4.1.5 is fixed in our deployment.
The deployment was working some weeks ago, but today I returned from vacation and no longer works, error message:
No package cassandra-4.1.5-* available.

Inspecting the repository https://apache.jfrog.io/ui/native/cassandra-rpm/41x/ I can see that version 4.1.5 is listed, but it is not returned when executing yum search / yum list:
$ yum list cassandra --showduplicates
Available Packages
cassandra.noarch 4.1~alpha1-1 cassandra
cassandra.src 4.1~alpha1-1 cassandra

A series of files were modified on 2024-08-03 (three days ago) in the directory https://apache.jfrog.io/ui/native/cassandra-rpm/41x/repodata - could this be the change that caused this behaviour?
We are now unable to install any version of Cassandra 4.1.x except the alpha release.
$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra.repo
[cassandra]
baseurl = https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/41x/
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS
name = apache cassandra repository
repo_gpgcheck = 1


Side note: the latest Cassandra installation documentation references 42x, but this does not exist on the repository remote: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/installing/installing.html

this should have been fixed as the above bug is now marked as Resolved. You should be able to download & install Cassandra RPM with the provided cassandra.repo file.
Also if you aren’t able to use Cassandra due to issues with GPG keys you can download & install the RPM via rpm -iVh (cassandra rpm link from JFrog)
